# 'If' executes even when the variable is false

Tags: c++

So, I know there are quite a few questions related to this on this website, but I couldn't find one that was like my problem.

```
cout<<"Please enter one or more floating point numbers"<<endl<<"When finished, enter 'q'"<<endl;

while(!done)

{
    cin>>Next;
    char letter;
    double temp;
    letter=Next[0];
    if (letter=='q')
        done=true;

    if (!done)
       temp = stod(Next);
       cout<<"temp is "<<temp<<" Next is "<<Next<<endl;
       localdata.push_back(temp);
}
```

And the standard output, upon entering `100.0`, `10.0`, `1.0` and `q` is like this -

```
Please enter one or more floating point numbers
When finished, enter 'q'
100.0
The value of done is 0
temp is 100 Next is 100.0
10.0
The value of done is 0
temp is 10 Next is 10.0
1.0
The value of done is 0
temp is 1 Next is 1.0
q
The value of done is 1
temp is 1 Next is q
```

So, the problem is that when the standard input is `q`, the value of `done` should change to `true`, but **still** the next `if(!done)` gets executed, which it shouldn't.

What could be the problem? I know it must be something fairly obvious, but I can't put my finger on it!

Comment: C++ isn’t Python. Only `temp = ...` is inside your `if`, the others are outside and execute always. Remember {}

Comment: use if else. you have two ifs and it will trigger always.

Comment: C++ uses curly braces to denote an `if` block.  Indenting code does nothing.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank you so much, that was quick! Rookie mistake from my side

Comment: @user1993 In general, **never** use another language to figure out what to do in C++.  Even languages that look 98% like C++, don't use them as a guide in writing code or figuring out how to write C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the heads up. Will keep in mind. Coming from Python, I kinda got used to its slightly more user-friendliness :)

Comment: @user1993 -- Well it could be worse -- you could have been a Java or C# programmer and thus make a total mess out of writing very basic C++ code by using Java / C# as a model.

Comment: [GCC warns about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8b0j5V)

Comment: Did you notice that the value of `temp` did not change after you entered `q`? Suggesting that `temp = stod(Next);` did not execute that time? Noticing small details like that can clue you in to what's wrong with your code. (Debuggers and compiler warnings are also helpful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted braces. In C++, without braces, `if` only takes the first line. You should use braces:

```
if (!done) {
    temp = stod(Next);
    cout<<"temp is "<<temp<<" Next is "<<Next<<endl;
    localdata.push_back(temp);
}
```

You can leave `if (letter=='q')` as is (the first line is taken), but it's the best if you use {} everywhere.